# .Eml file gets blocked while downloading on Edge browser

Tags: html, sharepoint, microsoft-edge, spfx

I want to deploy a SPFx application on SharePoint which consists of functionality where loaded data is being added to the email template which user will download with a extension of .eml. it works fine in chrome but every user might not be using chrome browser and on Edge it gets blocked.

How can we allow download of it? are there alternatives for that?

We can't change the approach of the functionality we need to have it as a download.

I tried with .msg extension too but it didn't worked either.

P.S. - I'm aware about the already provided solution. But it won't be possible to change anything in registry or something else.